# Authorization not working on custom authorizeattribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, custom-attributes

I've created an extremely simple authorization attribute for my MVC controller that is meant to redirect to a controller that allows displays a "not authorized" message:

```
public class ReportAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
        {
            { "action", "ReportDenied" }
            , { "controller", "Authorization"}
        });
    }
}
```

I'm applying it to my main site controller:

```
[ReportAuthorize(Roles=@"Domain\GroupName")]
public class ReportController : Controller
{
     //etc
}
```

I get kicked out even though I'm in the @"Domain\GroupName". In fact if I change it to Users=@"Domain\MyUserName" it still fails!

I've traced it to an IIS setting Anonymous Authentication, which is enabled for the site. Unfortunately, I cannot disable anonymous access on our production system because this project is part of a larger MVC project with many other controllers that don't have the right attributes. However, when I change it locally in IIS, I get in normally.

Now if I change to the normal authorize attribute:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"Domain\GroupName")]
public class ReportController : Controller
{
    //etc
}
```

I get in (I assume because I haven't defined any special behavior for when an unauthorized user tries to connect).

What are my options for getting this attribute situation resolved? I just need to get the ReportsAuthorize attribute to properly authenticate users before kicking them out for being anonymous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so after some aches and pains I finally got around this issue. Remember that part of the issue is that this controller is in a larger project that doesn't have the benefit of being able to disable anonymous authentication in IIS.

Here's the controller:

```
[ReportAuthorize(Users = @"domain\me,domain\etc", Roles = @"domain\groupname")]
[Authorize]
public class ReportController : Controller
{
    //etc
}
```

Here's the authorize attribute:

```
public class ReportAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (Users.Contains(httpContext.User.Identity.Name) || Roles.Split(',').Any(s => httpContext.User.IsInRole(s))) //this if checks users and roles using OR logic
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
        {
            {"action", "ReportDenied"}
            ,
            {"controller", "Authorization"}
        }); //this redirect sends you to a "not permitted" page
    }
}
```

I needed the authorize attribute to make the site check the domain and load the account information. Then the custom attribute that overrides authorizationcore verifies the values using OR logic (instead of the default AND logic, demonstrated by using two authorize attributes with one containing the users/roles you need).

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought you would want to check if the current user is authenticated (`filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`).

If not, call `base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest` which will presumably end up sending a challenge for Windows credentials.

If the user is authenticated, implement your redirect logic.

Having said that, wouldn't it be simpler to use the standard `AuthorizeAttribute` and use custom errors to display a "Not authorized" page?

Comment: The problem with the standard authorizeattribute is that if I put down a groupname I'm not a part of it challenges me for my credentials but fails to authenticate me properly and repeatedly asks until I cancel.

Comment: @CBauer - if the prompt is a problem for you, then yes, go for the custom attribute.  In my experience it hasn't been a problem, because I would use something like MvcSiteMapProvider with security trimming enabled so that users don't see links to URLs they are not authorized for.  Therefore users are rarely if ever confronted by the prompt.

Comment: Unfortunately the pages I'm trying to secure are sites that will be disseminated by direct links, and it would just be easier for everyone if I could target a role and have people without that role forwarded to a "You are not permitted to access this resource" page.